# Why is Safari using the webserver credentials instead of the login credentials when sending api requests?

Tags: angular, service, safari, basic-authentication, credentials

The service I use in the Angular app uses Basic Auth but also the server on which the app runs. Safari is the only browser which instead of using the credentials stored in the webstorage and retreived via:

```
this.service.configuration.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basic_token")).username;

this.service.configuration.password = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basic_token")).password;
```

uses the credentials used for the server Basic Auth. I see this in DeveloperTools-> Network. The bug happens only on some versions of Safari and only in production (localhost uses the right credentials).

Below the service:

```
public service(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
let headers = this.defaultHeaders;
if (this.configuration.username || this.configuration.password) {
headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.configuration.username + ':' + this.configuration.password));

// headers are printed with correct User and password
console.log(headers);
}

....................

return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.basePath}/service`,
{ 

withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
headers: headers,
observe: observe,
reportProgress: reportProgress
});}
```

Any ideas what causes the bug?

Thank you!